# SVG linearGradient DOM changes only working on Chrome

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to change the colors of an svg linearGradient using jquery but my code only works on Chrome.

Can any one help me out here to make it cross browser?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

          $(".input-holder:first .form-control").focusout(function(e) {
            var colorValue = $(this).val();
   var s = "#" + colorValue;
   var patt = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})$/;
   var matches = patt.exec(s);
   var rgb = "rgb("+parseInt(matches[1], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[2], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[3], 16)+")";
   
   $(this).next(".color-rgba").html(rgb);
   var getColor = $("lineargradient#grad1 stop:first").css('stop-color');
   //alert(getColor);
   $("lineargradient#grad1 stop:first").css('stopColor',rgb);
        });
  $(".input-holder:eq(1) .form-control").focusout(function(e) {
            var colorValue = $(this).val();
   var s = "#" + colorValue;
   var patt = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})$/;
   var matches = patt.exec(s);
   var rgb = "rgb("+parseInt(matches[1], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[2], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[3], 16)+")";
   
   $(this).next(".color-rgba").html(rgb);
   $("lineargradient#grad1 stop:eq(1)").css('stopColor',rgb);
   //$("lineargradient#grad1 stop:eq(1)").css('-moz-stop-color',rgb);
        });
   
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-holder">
                 <label>First Gradient Color</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <em class="color-rgba"></em>
                </div>
                <div class="input-holder">
                 <label>Second Gradient Color</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <em class="color-rgba"></em>
                </div>
                
                <svg height="150" width="400">
      <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="70%" y2="0%">
         <stop id="stp1" class="stop1" offset="50%" style="" />
       <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(13,93,0);stop-opacity:1" />
     </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is case sensitive so its linearGradient and not lineargradient. In other words you *should* need this:

```
$("linearGradient#grad1 stop:eq(1)").css('stopColor',rgb);
```

Unfortunately this won't work on Chrome as Chrome incorrectly requires element names to be lowercased.

The usual workaround for Chrome is to give all the linearGradientElements a class of linearGradient and then select by class rather than by element name. In your case since you've given the gradient an id, you could just use that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

          $(".input-holder:first .form-control").focusout(function(e) {
            var colorValue = $(this).val();
   var s = "#" + colorValue;
   var patt = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})$/;
   var matches = patt.exec(s);
   var rgb = "rgb("+parseInt(matches[1], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[2], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[3], 16)+")";
   
   $(this).next(".color-rgba").html(rgb);
   var getColor = $("#grad1 stop:first").css('stop-color');
   //alert(getColor);
   $("#grad1 stop:first").css('stopColor',rgb);
        });
  $(".input-holder:eq(1) .form-control").focusout(function(e) {
            var colorValue = $(this).val();
   var s = "#" + colorValue;
   var patt = /^#([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})([\da-fA-F]{2})$/;
   var matches = patt.exec(s);
   var rgb = "rgb("+parseInt(matches[1], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[2], 16)+","+parseInt(matches[3], 16)+")";
   
   $(this).next(".color-rgba").html(rgb);
   $("#grad1 stop:eq(1)").css('stopColor',rgb);
   //$("#grad1 stop:eq(1)").css('-moz-stop-color',rgb);
        });
   
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-holder">
                 <label>First Gradient Color</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <em class="color-rgba"></em>
                </div>
                <div class="input-holder">
                 <label>Second Gradient Color</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <em class="color-rgba"></em>
                </div>
                
                <svg height="150" width="400">
      <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad1" class="linearGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="70%" y2="0%">
         <stop id="stp1" class="stop1" offset="50%" style="" />
       <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(13,93,0);stop-opacity:1" />
     </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
            </div>
```